# Cannot sort data frame by date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with stocks names, prices and trading days. Like this:

```
        x     tradedate trading_volume trading_value 
     1 JIG    03/01/2012     055556               23
     2 JIG    04/01/2012     111111               43
     3 ABC    03/01/2012     715455               73
     4 ABC    04/01/2012     000000               39
```

I want to sort the data by date. I tried this code:

```
df$tradedate = as.Date(df$tradedate, format="%d.%m.%Y")
df[with(df, order(df$tradedate)), ]
```

and also this:

```
df[order(as.Date(df$tradedate, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]
```

But it doesn't work: There code runs... but the data is not ordered!

Comment: It certainly works here. If you want to store your data frame ordered, you have to assign it again to your `df` variable : `df<-df[order(as.Date(df$tradedate, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]`

Comment: I suppose your attempt with `format="%d.%m.%Y"` was a typo, given "03/01/2012" et c.

Comment: Yes it was a typo.. doesn't work with %d/%m/%Y

Comment: I posted an answer without reading the comments.  @juba can post an answer if you want and I can delete mine.

Comment: @MarkMiller Thanks, but it's ok, just undelete your answer, I'm fine with the +2 on my comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my.data <- read.table(text='
        x     tradedate trading_volume trading_value 
      JIG    03/01/2012     055556               23
      JIG    04/01/2012     111111               43
      ABC    03/01/2012     715455               73
      ABC    04/01/2012     000000               39
', header=TRUE)
my.data

my.data$tradedate <- as.Date(my.data$tradedate, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
my.data

my.data2 <- my.data[order(my.data$tradedate),]
my.data2

    x  tradedate trading_volume trading_value
1 JIG 2012-01-03          55556            23
3 ABC 2012-01-03         715455            73
2 JIG 2012-01-04         111111            43
4 ABC 2012-01-04              0            39
```